# Can I change emacs' notion of the first column? (From zero to one)

Tags: emacs

Emacs column-number-mode numbers columns from 0 which normally doesn't cause me any grief, but I'm working with some line/column based data files whose spec starts with '1', and it would be a lot easier if I could either get emacs to do that, or find some elisp to.

Thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot easily change Emacs to have 1-based column counting, the change would have to be in the C code.

However, you can calculate your own column and put that in the mode line.  Note: this requires the use of the `force-mode-line-update` - which could potentially slow down your Emacs (just keep it in mind in case two years from now Emacs feels sluggish on some large buffer).

```
;; update the mode line to have line number and column number
(setq mode-line-position 
      '("%p (%l," (:eval (format "%d)" (1+ (current-column))))))
;; force the update of the mode line so the column gets updated
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'force-mode-line-update)
```

Doc links of use are ['Variables Used In Mode Line'](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html) and ['Cursor Position Information'](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Position-Info.html).

Answer (score 12):

As of Emacs 26 (now released) there is a built in knob to fix this.

To use it, set
`(setq column-number-indicator-zero-based nil)`
in your .emacs

[Edited to reflect that Emacs 26 is now out.]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may be not the best answer, because I don't know emacs that good. I've edited `mode-line-position`, which is part of `mode-line-format`. Before use it, look to the original value, to know for sure that nothing is missing.

```
(setq mode-line-position
  '((-3 #("%p" 0 2 (help-echo "Size indication mode
mouse-1: Display Line and Column Mode Menu" mouse-face mode-line-highlight local-map (keymap (mode-line keymap (down-mouse-1 keymap (column-number-mode menu-item "Display Column Numbers" column-number-mode :help "Toggle displaying column numbers in the mode-line" :button (:toggle . column-number-mode)) (line-number-mode menu-item "Display Line Numbers" line-number-mode :help "Toggle displaying line numbers in the mode-line" :button (:toggle . line-number-mode)) "Toggle Line and Column Number Display"))))))
     (size-indication-mode (8 #(" of %I" 0 6 (help-echo "Size indication mode
mouse-1: Display Line and Column Mode Menu" mouse-face mode-line-highlight local-map (keymap (mode-line keymap (down-mouse-1 keymap (column-number-mode menu-item "Display Column Numbers" column-number-mode :help "Toggle displaying column numbers in the mode-line" :button (:toggle . column-number-mode)) (line-number-mode menu-item "Display Line Numbers" line-number-mode :help "Toggle displaying line numbers in the mode-line" :button (:toggle . line-number-mode)) "Toggle Line and Column Number Display")))))))
     "(%l,[%c"
     (:eval (format ",%d])" (1+ (current-column))))))
```

The main problem is that when you remove `%c` (column number) from mode-line-format, your `(:eval (current-column))` works very slow. I don't know how to make it better.